# Jquery Masonry with fixed height

Tags: jquery-masonry

I have a list of items that I want to display all with the same height, but different widths and dynamically generated.  I want them all to display in a way to use up as much white space as possible. I thought masonry would help, but it seems to be making weird gutters in between.

Is there an option in jquery-masonry or an alternative plugin that I should use instead?

HTML:

```
<div class="tagbox">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>technology</div>
  <div>search</div>
  <div>a longer test item</div>
  <div>another test</div>
  <div>development</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
display: block;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Javascript:

```
        $('.tagbox').masonry({
            itemSelector: 'div',
            isFitWidthBooleanfalse: true,
            gutterWidth: 0,
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                return containerWidth / 5;
            }
        });
```